# update the java version on Heroku for a nodejs app

Tags: java, node.js, heroku

To deploy Silex nodejs app to heroku, I need java 7 or newer to be available on heroku. This is because Silex front end is build with google closure compiler which requires java  version > 7

I tried the technique described in [Updating Existing Java Apps to Use Java 7 or Java 8](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app)

But it fails (there is still java 6), and I guess this is because it is a nodejs app :-/

So how can I update the java version on Heroku for a nodejs app?

Comment: Heroku buildpack (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) does not even download/install JVM when node.js application is detected. You should look for different buildpack for your application. You can also create your own buildpack - more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: Ah ok thank you
There is java 6 though because Silex used to deploy with an older version of google closure
I'll try with my custom buildpack thx

Comment: You can find have a look at some exemplary Heroku buildpacks which use using Google Closure Compiler e.g. https://github.com/ripple/heroku-buildpack-webassets. I hope that will help.

Comment: thx tom for the info
looks like https://github.com/ripple/heroku-buildpack-webassets do not manage to build with the latest google closure compiler... I'll dig